# Printing out last parent folder in file structure, but getting duplicates...possibly need to override equals and hashCode?

Tags: java, hashset

I'm working on a program that will go through a system's file structure and recursively determine, and print out, what are the last parent folders in the structure.  So for example, if I have a system that is set up like this:

```
C:\aaa\bbb\ccc\file1.txt
C:\aaa\bbb\ccc\file2.txt
C:\aaa\bbb\ddd\fileA.txt
```

The program will print out: "ccc" and "ddd".

However, a lot of the final parent folders contain more than one file.  In fact, almost all do.  I don't want to print out duplicate folder names, so I tried using a HashSet, as I know sets do not allow duplicates.  But my set is indeed adding duplicates.

I have done some reading, and I figured this is probably a case in which I need to override the equals() and hashCode() methods.  But I have two questions related to this:

1) Since I am adding String objects to the HashSet, not objects of a new/unique classtype, why do I need to override these methods?  I understand why Java might not know how to compare objects of a unique classtype, but it knows how to compare Strings, so...?

2) If I do need to override equals() and hashCode(), my code currently doesn't contain any non-static fields that could be used to do such a comparison, and I am unsure as to what is the best way to go about extracting a non-static field from my present code.

Here is the code I have so far.  It will run, and will print out tons of duplicate values:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class FileInformationMain {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        System.out.println("File System Roots returned by File.listRoots(): ");
        System.out.println();
        File [] f = File.listRoots();

        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Drive: " + f[i]);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("List of lowest level parent directories: ");
            File [] files = f[i].listFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File file : files) {
                    getFileNames(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void getFileNames(File aFile) {
        set <String> parents = new HashSet<String>();
        if (!aFile.isDirectory()) {
            set.add(aFile.getParent());
        }
        else {
            File [] children = aFile.listFiles();
            if (children != null) {
                for (int x = 0; x < children.length; x++) {
                    getFileNames(children[x]);
                }
        } 
        for (String string : parents) System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you print the contents of the hashset? You are using the method recursively, but never return anything and the code to print the contents is not part of any method. Please provide the proper code you are using.

Comment: What do you mean, "use a set"?  A set is an interface, don't you need a concrete type to instantiate something?

Comment: Stephan, I do print the contents, it's the last line of the code.

Comment: Each recursive call instantiates a new set (well it does not even compile in your code).

Comment: Edit: Sorry, I just realized I had a print statement in the wrong place; it has been moved

Comment: For each call in the stack, you just print one string (the parent of the passed-in file). You do that for any call though, so you actually print the full tree parents.

Comment: @guido, yes, you're correct.  The hashset instantiation shouldn't have been happening every time, that was the problem.  Thanks! Edit: and yes, I know at this point it's printing the full tree.  I will go back and edit that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Set` object is working properly in that it is not adding duplicate `String` objects. The problem lies in the way you are calling the recursive method. You are creating a new `Set` object each time the method is called, and you are printing its contents at the end of the method. The `Set` instance should be passed to the method recursively so that it gets filled with unique parent path names. Then at the end of the recursive call, you would print out the list of path names:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class FileInformationMain {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       System.out.println("File System Roots returned by File.listRoots(): ");
       System.out.println();
       File[] f = File.listRoots();

       Set<String> parents = new HashSet<String>();
       for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
           System.out.println("Drive: " + f[i]);
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println("List of lowest level parent directories: ");
           File[] files = f[i].listFiles();
           if (files != null) {
               for (File file : files) {
                   getFileNames(file, parents);
               }
           }
       }
       for (String string : parents)
           System.out.println(string);
   }

   public static void getFileNames(File aFile, Set<String> parents) {
       if (!aFile.isDirectory()) {
           parents.add(aFile.getParent());
       } else {
           File[] children = aFile.listFiles();
           if (children != null) {
               for (int x = 0; x < children.length; x++) {
                   getFileNames(children[x], parents);
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This did it!  Stupid me.  Thank you manouti (and guido, who alluded to this in his comment above)!